# Programatic signalling of Aurelia value converter

Tags: aurelia

I'm trying to get signalling working in value converters outside of the typical aurelia templating process.

I want to be able to signal my value converter to re-bind (as per https://aurelia.io/docs/binding/value-converters#signalable-value-converters) but I have a dynamic template and I'm applying the value converter by just getting it from the container and calling `myconverter.toView(params).`

Doing it this way is bypassing the calling of `ValueConverter.prototype.connect` which occurs as part of the template binding process. `ValueConverter.prototype.connect` is where the signals are registered, so my signal is not being picked up...

Answer (score 0):

As you have noticed, signaling can & should be understood as a way to notified all binding that are connected with some particular value converters, if there is no connection, there's no one to receive the signals.

For your case, what I understand is you want to reuse some functionalities/methods/utilities from that value converter. If so, I think it can be achieved via extracting the utility bit out of that value converter and make it reusable where you want to do `myconverter.toView(params)` instead?